# Where do you close a writer in TwitterStream?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm working on compiling a bunch of tweets for an information retrieval class. I'm trying this using both the REST API and the Streaming API through twitter4j. When using the Streaming API, I use the following modifications to [this example](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintSampleStream.java):

```
final LimitedFileWriter output = new LimitedFileWriter("Tweets","tweets");
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            try{
                output.write("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " -- " + status.getText()+"\n");
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.sample("en");
    //output.close();
```

It seems I can't ever close my writer. The writer I am using simply wraps BufferedWriter, while keeping track of file size. If the file exceeds a certain size (128MB), the writer will close the current file and create a new file. Here are the relevant class functions:

```
public void write(String s) throws IOException
{
    if(bytesWritten + s.getBytes(charset).length >= MAXSIZE){
        output.close();
        bytesWritten = 0;
        fileNum++;
        String fileName = directory + "/" + baseName+fmt.format(fileNum);
        currentFile = new File(fileName);
        output = new BufferedWriter
            (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName),charset));
    }

    output.write(s);
    bytesWritten += s.getBytes(charset).length;

}

public void close() throws IOException{
    output.close();
}
```

If I try to close the writer after `twitterStream.sample()` (commented out), the program crashes because I am trying to write to a closed file. If my understanding is correct, this is because the TwitterStream class creates a new thread which runs concurrently with the `main` thread. Then, the `main` thread closes the stream and the `twitterStream` can no longer write to it.

If that's the case, where should I close my writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to be able to turn of the tweets collection at some point, close your open file writers and have a clean exit. To achieve it you can use a synchronized block.

```
final Object lock = new Object();
final LimitedFileWriter output = new LimitedFileWriter("Tweets","tweets");
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        try{
        output.write("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " -- " + status.getText()+"\n");
        // free the lock
        if (some_condition_like_I_have_enough_files) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.sample("en");

try {
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.wait();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// close the twitterstream
// close the writer
```